# Makefile not linking required dependency

Tags: make, gnu-make

The two target executables are made successfully at first:

```
$ rm build/* bin/*
$ make
g++ -Wall -g -c -o build/Person.o src/Person.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -c -o build/PersonTests.o test/PersonTests.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestPerson build/Person.o build/PersonTests.o
g++ -Wall -g -c -o build/State.o src/State.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -c -o build/StateTests.o test/StateTests.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestState build/State.o build/StateTests.o
```

However when I edit  PersonTests.cpp (containing the main function), it does not recognise the members of the class I am attempting to test:

```
$ touch test/PersonTests.cpp
$ make
g++ -Wall -g -c -o build/PersonTests.o test/PersonTests.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestPerson build/PersonTests.o
build/PersonTests.o: In function `main':
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Person::Cross(Person&, Person&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:15: undefined reference to `Person::CrossBack(Person&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:17: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Person const&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:17: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Person const&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:17: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Person const&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Person::Cross(Person&, Person&)'
Bridge/test/PersonTests.cpp:20: undefined reference to `Person::CrossBack(Person&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'bin/TestPerson' failed
make: *** [bin/TestPerson] Error 1
```

Then using make again works ? Shown:

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestPerson build/Person.o build/PersonTests.o
```

I am new to using make and assume my issue is due to my Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

#------EXECUTABLES------
all : bin/TestPerson bin/TestState #bin/BridgeSolution

bin/BridgeSolution : build/main.o   build/Person.o build/State.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
bin/TestPerson     : build/Person.o build/PersonTests.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
bin/TestState      : build/State.o  build/StateTests.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
#-----------------------

#-----TEST_OBJECTS------
build/PersonTests.o : test/PersonTests.cpp build/Person.o include/Person.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
build/StateTests.o  : test/StateTests.cpp  build/State.o include/State.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
#-----------------------

#--------OBJECTS--------
build/main.o   : src/main.cpp   include/State.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
build/Person.o : src/Person.cpp include/Person.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
build/State.o  : src/State.cpp  include/State.h include/Person.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
#-----------------------
```

I understand the issue is to do with the difference in the output lines :

```
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestPerson build/Person.o build/PersonTests.o
```

```
g++ -Wall -g -o bin/TestPerson build/PersonTests.o
```

But I dont know why this is happening

Comment: I suspect your build rules for the executables need `$^` rather than `$?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the Makefile:

```make
bin/BridgeSolution : build/main.o   build/Person.o build/State.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
bin/TestPerson     : build/Person.o build/PersonTests.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
bin/TestState      : build/State.o  build/StateTests.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $?
```

you need to use `$^`, not `$?`. `$?` represents the subset of prerequisites which are newer than the target; thus, when you edit `PersonTests.cpp` after building `TestPerson`, Make rebuilds `PersonTests.o`, and that’s the only prerequisite of `TestPerson` which is newer than `TestPerson`, so `$?` becomes `TestPerson.o`.

If you write

```
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

instead, the recipe will be expanded to include all prerequisites all the time.